# Заменить подстроку, регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Сразу оговорюсь, с регулярными не так часто сталкиваюсь

Есть значение в переменной:

> define('COOKIE_PATH','project0');

в нем необходимо поменять параметр project0

Моё решение:

```
$strings =~ s/('COOKIE_PATH'\s*,\s*)'\w*'/$1'555'/g;
```

Проблема в том, что на месте `project0` может быть не только буквы и цифры, но еще и **/**

Как заменить к примеру вот такое значение:

> define('COOKIE_PATH','/project0');

Comment: язык программирования какой? perl?

Comment: @KoVadim да, perl. Изначально хотел включить в описание вопроса, но потом решил что не в этом суть :)

Comment: регулярки хоть и похожи, но в разных языках есть свои особенности.

Comment: кхм 

    preg_replace('#(["\']COOKIE_PATH["\'],["\'])(?:.*?)(["\'])#', '$1'.'file'.'$2', "define('COOKIE_PATH','/project0');")

С языком не угадал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$strings =~ s/('COOKIE_PATH'\s*,\s*)'[\w\/]*'/$1'555'/g;` пойдёт?

Comment: да, спасибо ) оказывается я был близко сам дотыкаться до нужного решения )

Comment: Пожалуйста!

Comment: я бы пошел дальше и  написал так

    $strings =~ s/('COOKIE_PATH'\s*,\s*)'[^']*'/$1'555'/g;

Comment: @KoVadim: можно и так, но мне нравятся более жёсткие парсеры, которые не пропускают непредусмотренные символы. Вопрос личных предпочтений, конечно.

Comment: @KoVadim а откуда такая любовь к слешам (`/`).

        $strings =~ s{('COOKIE_PATH'\s*,\s*)'[\w/]*'}{$1'555'}g;

Ежели мне склероз не изменяет.

Comment: я просто скопировал у @VladD и подменил пару символов. А что писать - слеши или фигурные скобки - это по обстоятельствам.

Comment: @KoVadim ну обстоятельства тут против слешей -- слеш в исследуемом выражении. Но вот к чему мне трудно привыкнуть (аж воротит) -- это к `[\w]` (использование метасимволов для обозначения классов). Ну неправильно это.

Comment: в моем выражении слешей нет, так что мне ничего не мешает. да и `\w` я не использую. Посмотрите внимательно, какое я выражение написал.